# Cannot join two dataframes in pandas. ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes I want to join

```
df1.join(df2, how = 'left', on = "foo")
```

I get

> ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat

But, both columns `foo` are of type `object`.

```
print(df1.dtypes)
```

This gives me

```
foo         object
geometry    geometry
dtype: object
```

Looking at the `dtypes` of `df2`

```
print(df2.dtypes)
```

This gives me

```
foo         object
bar         object
num         int64
dtype: object
```

`foo` is in both `dataframe` of type `object`. Even a

```
df1.dtypes["foo"] == df2.dtypes["foo"]
```

returns a `True`

Why do I get this error message?

Answer (score 1):

`df1.join(df2, on='foo')` attempts to join df1['foo'] to the *index* of df2 (which is likely int64). To merge two dataframes on columns use `pd.merge`

Comment: How would I join on a common column name then?

Comment: Yeah that should work, can you find a key that occurs in both and check what the value is `df.loc['key', 'foo']` ? I'm wondering if maybe there is whitespace or something that makes them look the same but not compare equal